# Problems in python trying to open 2 terminals

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, console, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a python script that allows you to open 2 terminals simultaneously, it works fine, but if I try to insert it into a loop the 2nd terminal doesn't open and it skips to the next statement, here is the code that works fine:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import threading as th

    def run(command):
            cmd = Popen(command, PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
            com, err = cmd.communicate()
            print(com,err)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        mp.freeze_support()
        command = f"python testFile.py"  # or command = f"testFile.exe"
        process = mp.Process(target=run, args= (command,))
        process.start()
        input("Wait ")
```

as I said this works fine, but if I try to insert it in a loop the 2nd terminal doesn't open:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import threading as th

    def run(command):
        cmd = Popen(command, PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
        com, err = cmd.communicate()
        print(com,err)

    while True:
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            mp.freeze_support()
            command = f"python testFile.py"  # or command = f"testFile.exe"
            process = mp.Process(target=run, args= (command,))
            process.start()
            input("Wait ")
```

Comment: Why create two terminals? If your code is to function in two terminals...wouldn't that mean 2 separate programs?

Comment: I want to open another program, but I don't want to use 'os.startfile('path')', because I have to share this program to my friends and I can't know where the file path will be saved